Serializing data to json with multiple circular dependencies
I'm working on some code that serializes and deserializes a complex data structure.
I have a data model in C# consisting of three classes: TypeA, TypeB, and TypeC.
TypeA has a reference to TypeB, TypeB has a reference to TypeA, and TypeC has references to two instances of TypeB.
When attempting to serialize these objects using System.Text.Json, I encounter issues due to the circular dependencies.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;

public class TypeA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TypeB LinkedB { get; set; }
}

public class TypeB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public TypeA LinkedA { get; set; }
}

public class TypeC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public TypeB Reference1 { get; set; }
    public TypeB Reference2 { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectToSerialize
{
    public List<TypeA> Data { get; set; }

    public List<TypeC> links { get; set; }
}

I don't really care about what the serialized data looks like because I'm going to deserialize it back into the same data model with the same code.
I've already looked at RefrenceHandler, but I feel like that only solves one of the two references and not both. (Correct me if I'm wrong)
I'm looking for a solution to serialize these objects using System.Text.Json so that the original references stay intact.
How can I achieve this while staying close to the original data model and the default way System.Text.Json serializes objects?
I'm open to writing custom converters, modifying the data model, or using a different serialization library if necessary.
Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Can you give an example input C# object you want to serialize, and the expected output JSON?

Why serialize the complete type as reference and not just its Id?

I've updated the question. But in short, I have a fourth object with a list of TypeA and a list of TypeC. That is the object I want to serialize.
As for the output, I don't really care about the format, as the same code can deserialize it back to the original data.
An why I want to serialize the references. The JSON can contain the IDs but when its deserialized then I would like to receive the references again

I've already looked at RefrenceHandler, but I feel like that only solves one of the two references and not both. (Correct me if I'm wrong) -- might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] demonstrating incorrect JSON round-tripping when using a System.Text.Json reference handler?

"The JSON can contain the IDs but when its deserialized then I would like to receive the references again" That sounds like you are are trying to use just one model for everything. Its good practice to have different models for different purposes. SO one for transport and one for internal logic. One with just the Id for the references and one with actual instances.

Please try the example below and let me know if that fixed your issue:
        var typeA = new TypeA
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Name",
        };

        var typeBFirst = new TypeB
        {
            Id = 1,
            Description = "Description 1",
            LinkedA = typeA
        };

        typeA.LinkedB = typeBFirst;

        var typeBSecond = new TypeB
        {
            Id = 2,
            Description = "Description 2",
            LinkedA = typeA
        };

        var typeC = new TypeC
        {
            Id = 1,
            Note = "Note",
            Reference1 = typeBFirst,
            Reference2 = typeBSecond
        };

        JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
        {
            ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
            WriteIndented = true
        };

        var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(typeC, options);

You can read more here How to preserve references and handle or ignore circular references in System.Text.Json

Thank you for simplifying the question. The example showed me that serialization is not the problem.
The problem lies in all the other fluff I surrounded it with. I'm now on my way of solving the problem thanks.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

It turns out that my situation is totally doable with the native System.Text.Json.
There were two problems:
you need ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve as one of your JsonSerializerOptions. With this option, the serializer uses $id and $ref in the JSON to indicate references.
Secondly, you need to make sure that your classes are wide open. This was my main problem.

Your setters and getters need to be available.
You need a default constructor for every class.
You need to annotate your private fields that need serializing with [JsonInclude]
All read-only properties need at least a init setter

I want to thank everybody for their answers and comments.
PS. The versions I'm using at his time are .NET8 and C# 12
